# How can a parent View get data of an active child view in Prism?

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism

Is there a common known way to get the data from a ViewModel which is currently active in a region? Consider this:

1. A shell has a MainAppView which is bound to a MainAppViewModel.
2. MainAppView has a region which has a collection of navigatable ChildViews with their corresponding ChildViewModels loaded from discovered modules.
3. These ChildModels are all different from each other and they work with different objects. The only thing they have in common are interfaces: IChildView, IChildViewModel and also the object that IChildViewModel operates with is an IObject. Don't miss this please, IObject interface is the only thing MainAppView knows about the object the child works with.

What I want is to get an instance of an IObject which is withing an active ChildView and of course I need to have it in my MainAppViewModel and pass it to a service which only knows an IObject interface and nothing more.

Thank you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass it directly to the service from whichever child view model has it. Noone said that only main app view models are allowed to interact with services...

Comment: Hmm, well to clearify more: IObjects are actually data providers and child views/viewmodels are ui and logic to configure these different providers (connection strings, source file, parsing settings and many more other) every IObject is different except that it can retrieve data from some source... Wouldn't it turn out if I do it your way, that I'll have to teach every such (data reader) modul to talk to the (data processor) service insead of doing it it one place from the Main parent where it logically fits? Though... I'll try and see... Can be an option. Thank you)

Comment: `doing it it one place` - that's perfectly reasonable, but it does not need to happen in a view model, in fact it should not. That's the job description for a new service.

Comment: I also came up with a service solution. It seems like this problem's scenario is one of those where prism doesn't shine. It breaks the parent child direct relationship... At least for me it seems logical that a parent must be able to directly contol children - he is the parent, the host and the God of an application. Making an extra service to do such a simple things is like standing right in from of you own son and using a phone to talk to him))) You know what I mean) I think I'll just keep what I have for now and if I find any elegant way in the future I'll come back to this issue.

Comment: True to a certain degree, but first and foremost the view model's job is to aggregate data for its view. It creates the child view models, but they do their own thing... and btw - the parent view model can interact with (or control, for that matter) its child view models, of course, if need be. Think of a collection of child view models exposed as a property and displayed in a `ListView`. If they're implemented by foreign modules, they must share an interface to expose functionality to the parent. Nothing wrong with that, if it's directly related to the view of the parent.